# Adding index.FilterField for Page object in Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

I need to implement a language-specific search in Wagtail, so I modified the default `search/views.py` like this:

```
def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get("query", None)
    page = request.GET.get("page", 1)
    language = request.LANGUAGE_CODE

    if search_query:
        search_results = Page.objects.live().filter(locale__language_code=language).search(search_query)
```

The result is an error message:

```
Please add index.FilterField('language_code') to Page.search_fields
```

Adding `index.FilterField('language_code')` to my classes derived from `Page` does not work – so how can I add that filter field index to `wagtailcore.Page`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `Locale.get_active()` as a shortcut to get the current language. It's worth looking at [defer_streamfields()](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.query.PageQuerySet.defer_streamfields), this will reduce the amount of data you're loading into memory also.

```py
Page.objects.live().defer_streamfields().filter(locale=Locale.get_active()).search(search_query)
```

If you're using the Wagtail search backend, it only supports one `SEARCH_CONFIG` even though you can add multiple in the settings. All that happens is each backend listed overwrites the previous and you end up with the last in the list. There is nothing in the `wagtailsearch_indexentry` table that allows for different backends.

If you have the following:

```
WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS = {
    'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
      'SEARCH_CONFIG': 'english_extended',
    },
    'es': {
      'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
      'SEARCH_CONFIG': 'spanish',
    },
    'fr': {
      'BACKEND': 'wagtail.search.backends.database',
      'SEARCH_CONFIG': 'french',
    },
}
```

In this case, the search backend will always be the French one, even if you specify the Spanish backend in your code with

```
from wagtail.search.backends import get_search_backend
s = get_search_backend('es')
scope = Page.objects.live().defer_streamfields().filter(locale=Locale.get_active())
search_results = s.search(search_query, scope)
```

`s` will be using the French `SEARCH_CONFIG` setting with French NLP (stemming and stop words) according to that dictionary instead.

Best solution I've come up with is to use the `simple` dictionary and extend it with PostgrSQL unaccent support (adds full character set support for plain ascii, e.g. typing "hotel" will return results with "hôtel" etc.).
https://enzedonline.com/en/tech-blog/how-to-add-unaccent-support-in-postgresql-search/#6-test-stemming-with-unaccent

That disables the NLP, but at least makes it language neutral.

I raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/9253) in 2022, but it never got any traction.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
def search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get("query", None)
    page = request.GET.get("page", 1)
    current_locale = Locale.objects.get(language_code=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)

    # Search
    if search_query:
        search_results = Page.objects.live().filter(locale=current_locale).search(search_query)
```